# Java Script TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, google-maps

Records are selected from a database and animated on a map. I am getting a **TypeError** in firebug console and i cannot find what is causing the error. No markers get plotted and no animation is occurring. Error is occuring in the **makeRouteCallback** function.

Using console.log() has revealed that rNum has the correct values 0,1,2,3,4.

**Error**

```
TypeError: polyline[rNum] is undefined
polyline[rNum].setMap(map);
```

I also did a console.log for 'status' in the **makeRouteCallback** function and it printed NOT_FOUND instead of OK

**Code**

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri= "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri= "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/crimeTrackMap.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />        
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAuJC5ega61cLlvCB14uKxoheUmh61Wwmc&sensor=true"></script>      
    <script src="/crimeTrack/resources/js/markermanager.js"></script>   

    <script src="/crimeTrack/resources/js/v3_epoly.js"></script>    

    <script src="/crimeTrack/resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService;
    var stepDisplay;

    var position;
    var marker        = [];
    var polyline      = [];
    var poly          = [];
    var poly2         = [];
    var startLocation = [];
    var endLocation   = [];
    var timerHandle   = [];    

    var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
    var infowindow = null;

    var myPano;   
    var panoClient;
    var nextPanoId;

    var global_citizens = new Array();


    var Colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"];

    //------------------------------------------------------------

    function GetCitizensForTracking(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async : false,
            global: 'false',
            url: 'getListOfMarkers.htm',
            headers : {Accept: 'application/json'},
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(citizens) {
            global_citizens = citizens;

            $.each(citizens, function(i, c) {
            //console.log(c.name + ' | ' + c.socialSecurityNumber + ' | ' + c.lat+ ' | ' +c.lng);
            //citizen.push(c.name);
            console.log(global_citizens[i].name+','+global_citizens[i].citizenType);

            });             
        });     
    }      


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

  function initialize() {  

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
      { 
        size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
      });

      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      address = 'Trinidad and Tobago'
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);

    });


    } 

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function createMarker(latlng, label, html,citizenType) {

     var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;

     //console.log('Citizen icon is '+citizenType);     

    //replaces if...then..else...else if. Icon source are placed in an array that corresponds to value of the citizenType.
    //array starts from 0 . The first value of the citizens type is 2 so array should have a value at the 2 location 
    //so jquery will map the icon to the citizenType based on its matching location in the array

      var markerSource = [null,
                          null,
                         'resources/icons/criminal_new.ico',
                         'resources/icons/victim_new.ico',
                         'resources/icons/suspect_new.ico'];

      var icon = markerSource[citizenType];


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latlng,
           map: map,
           title: label,
           icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon),
           zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
           });
           marker.myname = label;       

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
           infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
           infowindow.open(map,marker);
           });    

      return marker;
  }  

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function setRoutes(){ 

    var directionsDisplay = new Array();

    for (var i=0; i< global_citizens.length; i++){

    var rendererOptions = {
        map: map,
        suppressMarkers : true,
         preserveViewport: true
    }
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;  


    var request = {
        origin: global_citizens[i].startLat+','+global_citizens[i].startLng,
        destination: global_citizens[i].endLat+','+global_citizens[i].endLng,
        travelMode: travelMode
    };  

        directionsService.route(request,makeRouteCallback(i,directionsDisplay[i],global_citizens[i].citizenType));
        console.log("Set Routes "+global_citizens[i].name +' - '+global_citizens[i].citizenType);

    }   

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function makeRouteCallback(rNum, disp,ctype){   
     if (polyline[rNum] && (polyline[rNum].getMap() != null)) {
           startAnimation(rNum);
           return;
          }

        return function(response, status){      

          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var route = response.routes[0];
            startLocation[rNum] = new Object();
            endLocation[rNum] = new Object();


            polyline[rNum] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
            strokeWeight: 3
            });

            poly2[rNum] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
            strokeWeight: 3
            });     


            // For each route, display summary information.
            var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;

            disp = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);     
            disp.setMap(map);
            disp.setDirections(response);


            //Markers               
            for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
              if (i == 0) { 
                startLocation[rNum].latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                startLocation[rNum].address = legs[i].start_address;
                // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});               

                //console.log('(i) The Citizen Type Is : '+ global_citizens[i].citizenType);

                marker[rNum] = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,ctype);                    

              }

              endLocation[rNum].latlng = legs[i].end_location;
              endLocation[rNum].address = legs[i].end_address;
              var steps = legs[i].steps;

              for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;                
                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;

                for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
                    polyline[rNum].getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                    //bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);            


                }

              }
            }           
        }


         polyline[rNum].setMap(map);
         //map.fitBounds(bounds);        
        startAnimation(rNum);   

        }

    }  

  }
    var lastVertex = 1;
    var stepnum=0;
    var step = 90; //0.9 metres
    var tick = 100; // milliseconds
    var eol = [];
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------              
   function updatePoly(i,d) {
   // Spawn a new poly line every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
    if (poly2[i].getPath().getLength() > 20) {
            poly2[i]=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline[i].getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
            // map.addOverlay(poly2)
          }

      if (polyline[i].GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
          if (poly2[i].getPath().getLength()>1) {
              poly2[i].getPath().removeAt(poly2[i].getPath().getLength()-1)
          }
            poly2[i].getPath().insertAt(poly2[i].getPath().getLength(),polyline[i].GetPointAtDistance(d));
      } else {
          poly2[i].getPath().insertAt(poly2[i].getPath().getLength(),endLocation[i].latlng);
      }     

   }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function animate(index,d) {

     if (d>eol[index]) {

        marker[index].setPosition(endLocation[index].latlng);
        return;
     }
      var p = polyline[index].GetPointAtDistance(d);

      //map.panTo(p);
      marker[index].setPosition(p);
      updatePoly(index,d);
      timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate("+index+","+(d+step)+")", tick);




    if(marker[0].getPosition() == endLocation[0].latlng){
        console.log('Completed');
    //alert("Marker One Complete"); 
    }
  }

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function startAnimation(index) {
        if (timerHandle[index]) clearTimeout(timerHandle[index]);
          eol[index]=polyline[index].Distance();
          map.setCenter(polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0));

          poly2[index] = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#FFFF00", strokeWeight:3});

          timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate("+index+",50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display         

  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------      

 $(document).ready(function(){   


    $('#getCitizens').on('click', function() {

        if(global_citizens == undefined || global_citizens.length == 0 ){
            GetCitizensForTracking();    
            setRoutes();        
        }else{alert("Tracking In Progress");}

    });     


}); 


</script>





  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:90%">

    <!-- MAP GOES IN HERE -->

    </div>

    <div id="toolbar">
        <button class="btn" id="getCitizens" onclick="" type="button">Get Citizens</button>
        <button class="btn" id="startTracking" onclick="" type="button">Start Tracking</button>
        <button class="btn" id="pauseTracking" onclick="" type="button">Pause Tracking</button>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that triggers the error:

```
polyline[rNum].setMap(map);
```

...is not placed within the condition where you populate `polyline`

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
  //code
}
```

When the condition fails, the failing statement still will be executed....with an error.

Move the last 2 statements of the callback into the `status`-condition.

Comment: i did that an the errors are gone however my animation does not start. any suggestions ? 1+ for your answer

Comment: I think status is not OK

Comment: there will be nothing executed inside the callback when the status is **not** "OK". When status is `NOT_FOUND`(as you wrote in your question) the status of course is not `OK`

Comment: i am surrounding the code with a try catch to see whats the error

Comment: This code was working i dont know why all a sudden these errors start

Comment: there is no error, the status `NOT_FOUND` means that the directionsService was not able to find a direction between the given locations. It's not a matter of your code, it's a matter of your data(`global_citizens`) and the directionsService - response.

Comment: so this means it cannot find the routes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38454/discussion-between-dev-darin-and-dr-molle)

Comment: sorry, I don't like chats

Comment: can you assist with the error a little more my data seems to be good since i was using it and it wasn't giving errors.

Comment: can you post the data(especially the sets where no direction has been found)

Comment: i post the code that gets the data which returns the marker information

Comment: ok yes it was the data in the database table the conversion of long lat coordinates where inaccurate hence the routes not being able to be plotted. Coordinates were was off. Thanks alot for your time and patients. All is well again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare polyline variable as a dictionary, like this:

```
polyline = {}
```